# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' so I'm not sure what to try next for my ImageViewer

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I can't figure out why my code couldn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
"""
We need the Pillow library (or PIL) to import images in out application)
I need to import both ImageTk and Image
"""
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

"""
doens't work at the moment bc I can't figure out what's wrong with PIL
"""

root = Tk()
root.title("Icono, Boton Exit y Imagenes")
root.geometry("200x100")

'''
root.iconbitmap("c:/gui/codemy.ico")

this is to put a personalized icon to the window application
'''

my_img = imageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("something.png"))
my_label = Label(image=my_img)
my_label.pack()


button_quit = Button(root, text="Salir del programa", command=root.destroy) 
button_quit.pack()

"""
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-close-a-tkinter-window-with-a-button/

for other examples of exit button

also command=root.quit

"""

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to look it up around and from what I've been asked by others, I don't have two Python versions installed;

I installed Pillow;

And PIL I couldn't install since pip could not find it.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Thank you for reading my question.

EDIT:
This is the traceback.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "F:\python ejercicios\TkIconsImagesExitButtons.py", line 6, >in
>
> from PIL import ImageTk, Image
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Edit2:
These are the warnings which I Kind of find confusing?

> Line 6 : Name "Image" already defined (possibly by an import)
>
> Line 6 : Unused ImageTk imported from PIL
> It looks like the imported module or variable is not used.
>
> Line 22 : Name "imageTk" is not defined
>
> Line 22 : "Type[Image]" has no attribute "open"

Final edit: Found the problem. Thanks to those who tried to help me out.

Comment: It is better to provide the full traceback.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  Try using `python -m pip install -U Pillow` to install the module again.

Comment: I did it and nothing. Though the warnings are weird.

Comment: Those warnings are from the IDE you use.  The IDE may use its own virtual Python environment, so looks up document on the IDE.

Comment: I meant as in "Weird" as for example, telling me Image is already defined in line 6 when it shouldn't

Comment: `Image` is also a class in `tkinter` module which is already imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there you can try the following-

1. Make corrections in your code

   `my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("something.png"))`
2. Try to update your pip version by using the command in command prompt or powershell
   `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I didn't realize. It is now correct. As for the pip upgrade I already tried it yesterday and it didn't change the error. I tried it again and it only says the requirement has already been satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

So my actual problem was that I had more than one Python.exe installed and that Thonny (the IDE I use) didn't actually have the Pillow package so when I would run the app, it failed.
Thanks a lot for the help.